# Admin Panel System

Tags: php, authentication, system, admin

The stackoverflow aways helped, but this time I didn't found anythig about it.
I'm making a system, like the wordpress:
    /admin/
    /content/
    /index.php

So, as the WP, inside the 'content' will have the 'themes', but my question is not about it. The admin, of course, the user has to be logged in. How can I redirect EVERYTHING inside the /admin/* to my /admin/login.php ?
I found a code to use, like:

php code:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['logged_in']))
echo something;
else
redirect something;
```

But, I don't want make it in every page, I want like in a header.php, in the start do:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['logged_in']))
header ('Location: webpage');
```

HTMLCODE HERE.

But, I don't want load that html code, I want redirect first, before shows the HTML. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
header ('Location: /admin/login.php');
exit;
}
else
{
// HTML
}
```

Make sure you call header() before sending any other head information to the browser.

Comment: That is the same thing that I said, I don't want type in every page: "if empty session... else ...". I think that I'll create a functions.php, and a function is_logged, that will verify and if not, "header(Location: login.php); exit; ". That will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to atleast detect your account if you're an admin, then consider that you'd retrieved the sql data of the account and store it to session.

Let me consider `$_SESSION['user_id']` and `$_SESSION['user_prev']`, the user_id is your sql's account primary key, and the user_prev is the privilege, let me say

```
Member = 1
Developer = 50
Admin = 99
```

Those are the numbering of your privilege, ofcourse they must be stored in your database and retrieve the data...

We need to assume that a certain "VISITOR" did login...we don't know if it is a Member/Developer or Admin.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
     if(isset($_SESSION['user_prev'])) {
            /*We need to check if it is Admin or else it might be
             *a Developer or just a Member
             */
            if($_SESSION['user_prev'] == 99) {
                include_once 'admin_content.php';
            }elseif($_SESSION['user_prev'] == 50) {
                include_once 'developer_content.php';
            }else{
                include_once 'member_content.php';
            }
     }
}else {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

I used 'include_once' instead of redirecting the users into a certain content/php...this will also help you to secure your content...